# Anyone know of an online trailing whitespace remover?

Tags: javascript, whitespace, trim

I have a JS file (~2000 lines) and want to strip all trailing whitespace. I am using Coda and it has a plugin but it keeps crashing the app. I feel like this is a simple enough thing where there might be an online tool but I can not find one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I wrote you a little script: http://codepad.org/vZNPOF1a

Just paste in your code where it says, in the text area below, click submit, then click on the output link up above to get the raw output.

Comment: @crimson_penguin Thank you! Getting output of: "Disallowed system call: SYS_getgroups32" though... not sure what is up.

Comment: Hmm, your code doesn't have a line with just "CONTENT" on it, does it? Only other thing I can think of is either that it's too long (could try doing it in parts), or it has weird special characters.

Comment: No CONTENT, thought it was the length but tried shorter pieces and got compile errors. `syntax error at line 3, near "[]"
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: Ohhh, I'm sorry, it's my fault. It should work if you put single quotes around the first instance of CONTENT in the script. I would do this myself, but I'm on flakey 3G right now, and it's not loading.

Comment: Perfection. Thank you! I will now try to change the regex to remove trailing tabs too. ;)

Comment: It should already remove tabs; \s means "whitespace", and in fact tabs is what I tested it with. Anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var removeLineTrailingWhitespace = function(s) {
  return (""+s).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/mg, '');
};
var str = "foo    \n    bar    \n";
removeLineTrailingWhitespace(str); // => "foo\nbar";
```

Answer (score 1):

Load it up on Notepad++ and press `alt+shift+s`

Comment: which leads me to re-read the question again, so as a correction, please take note notepad++ does this offline.